# Windows Server 2019 cannot see devices on the LAN

Tags: network-shares, windows-server-2019

I just installed (and activated) Windows Server 2019 Standard.  It is set up in a workgroup and has the same workgroup name as all other PC's. All other PCs can access each other's shares (even the servers shares) but the server cannot see any shares. Given the server's IP address of 192.168.0.3, whenever I try to access another PC's share from the server using

```
\\192.168.0.4\Share1
```

After a few seconds, I get the following message

> Windows cannot access \\192.168.0.4\Share1.
>   Check the spelling of the name. Otherwise, there might be a problem with your network. To try to
>   identify and resolve network problems, click Diagnose.

Clicking Diagnose just tells me no issues were found.

The only things I can find when searching this issue are questions about not being able to access the server's shares.  That's not my issue.  The issue is that the server can't access the other shares on the network.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does `\\192.168.0.4` work (without the share name)? Can you ping `192.168.0.4` from the server?

Comment: No, it does not work with or without a share name.  And yes, it does ping from the server.

Comment: I should also say that in file explorer when you look at "Network", it finds all the other computers on the LAN. Double-clicking on any of them returns a similar message as described in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out and fixed it.  The answer was found [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e63f1d76-3913-4b33-85b5-e04581d59f8b/windows-server-2019-smb-share?forum=winserverfiles) and [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4046019/guest-access-in-smb2-disabled-by-default-in-windows-10-and-windows-ser).  Basically, Windows Server 2019 disables guest access in SMB2 by default.  Had to enable insecure guest logons in the group policy editor.

> Computerconfiguration\administrative templates\network\Lanman
>   Workstation "Enable insecure guest logons"

Answer (score 0):

@tolsen64's answer worked for me too - trying to access the NAS on my LAN was giving me the "Windows cannot access ..." error

SOLUTION: Edit Local Group Policy on your 2019 server: (run **gpedit.msc**)
Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Network\Lanman Workstation\
Set "Enable insecure guest logons" to "Enabled"

My current config:

- very fresh install of windows server 2019, as a hyper-v vm, running on "WORKGROUP"
- all windows updates brought current
- File and Network sharing is still turned OFF
- Windows Defender Firewall > Allowed Apps > ☑ Network Discovery ☑Private ☑ Public

Network Sharing Center > Advanced Sharing Options

- Private: Network Discovery & File and Printer sharing turned OFF
- Guest or Public: Network Discovery & File and Printer sharing turned OFF
- All Networks: Turn off Public Folder Sharing; Turn on password protected sharing.

Did not touch any Services settings

- SSDP Discovery - still Disabled
- UPnP Device Host - still Disabled